# Crear script para generar usuarios de dominio en Powershell

Tags: windows, revisión-de-código, powershell, directorioactivo, cuenta-usuario

Tengo que crear un script que me haga una GPO para el Grupo Alumnado y otra para el grupo profesorado, y crear un par de usuarios por grupo, sin embargo no se me ejecuta. El código que desarrollado es el siguinte:

```
 #Creamos las GPO

New-ADOrganizationalUnit Profesorado
New-ADOrganizationalUnit Alumnado
#Creamos los grupos de usuarios

New-ADGroup -Name "Profesorado" -SamAccountName Profesorado -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "Profesorado" -Path " OU=Profesorado,DC=ras2017,DC=org " -Description "Grupo del profesorado"
New-ADGroup -Name "Alumnado" -SamAccountName Alumnado -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "Redaccion Solvetic" -Path " OU=Redaccion,DC=solvetic,DC=com " -Description "Alumnado"

#Creamos los usuarios y los asiganmos en el grupo correspondiente

New-ADUser -Name Rafa -GivenName Rafa -Surname Aybar -Path "CN=Alumnado,DC=rafael,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
New-ADUser -Name Al1 -GivenName Al1 -Surname 2 -Path "CN=Alumnado,DC=rafael,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
New-ADUser -Name Al2-GivenName Al2-Surname 2 -Path "CN=Alumnado,DC=rafael,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
New-ADUser -Name Prof1 -GivenName 1 -Surname 1 -Path "CN=Profesorado,DC=rafael,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
New-ADUser -Name Prof2 -GivenName 2 -Surname 2 -Path "CN=Profesorado,DC=rafael,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
Add-ADGroupMember "Alumnado" Rafa,Al1,Al2
Add-ADGroupMember "Profesorado" Prof1,Prof2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está en la ruta, no tienes el *DN* de una *OU*.

Intenta cambiar esto:

> -Path "CN=Alumnado,DC=rafael,DC=org

Por esto:

> -Path "OU=Alumnado,DC=rafael,DC=org

Observa que el tuyo empieza por *CN*, debe ser *OU*.

Comment: Cesar, gracias por tu aporte y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Para que tengas en cuenta, Stack Overflow en Español cuenta con un privilegio llamado "comentarios", el cual, una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).